# How to view generated PDF from JapserReport to Primefaces Media Component?

Tags: primefaces, inputstream

I have the following Method that generates My PDF from Jasper as byte[].

```
    @Named
@ViewScoped
public class ReportingBean extends BasicBean {
...
    public void generateUebersichtMaterial() throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream pathMaster_jrxml;
        InputStream pathSubReport_jrxml;
        pathMaster_jrxml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/mainreport.jrxml");
        pathSubReport_jrxml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/subreport.jrxml");
        try {
            getConnection();
            HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            List<ReportMaterialUebersicht> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list = reportFacade.getReportMaterialUebersicht();
            JasperReport subreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathSubReport_jrxml);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathMaster_jrxml);
            params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH);
            params.put("subReport", subreport);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params,
                    new JRBeanArrayDataSource(list.toArray()));
            connection.close();
            content = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
            Faces.sendFile(content, "Materialuebersicht.pdf", false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportingBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Instead of open the PDF in a new window I want to use the primefaces media component like:

```
<p:media value="#{reportingBean.myPDF}" width="100%" height="100%" player="pdf" />
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve tried it out, and I found out the solution by myself by using the StreamedContent from Primefaces.

Added these two lines to the ReportBean:

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
myDoc = new DefaultStreamedContent(in, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
```

In the PostConstruct of the Bean I initilize the variable myPDF and call it from the media component.

```
<p:media value="#{reportingBean.myPDF}" width="100%" height="100%" player="pdf" />
```

Here is the full Bean example:

The ReportingBean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ReportingBean extends BasicBean {
...
private DefaultStreamedContent myPDF;
    public void generateUebersichtMaterial() throws FileNotFoundException {
        InputStream pathMaster_jrxml;
        InputStream pathSubReport_jrxml;
        pathMaster_jrxml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/mainreport.jrxml");
        pathSubReport_jrxml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/subreport.jrxml");
        try {
            getConnection();
            HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
            List<ReportMaterialUebersicht> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list = reportFacade.getReportMaterialUebersicht();
            JasperReport subreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathSubReport_jrxml);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(pathMaster_jrxml);
            params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH);
            params.put("subReport", subreport);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, params,
                    new JRBeanArrayDataSource(list.toArray()));
            connection.close();
            content = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
            Faces.sendFile(content, "Materialuebersicht.pdf", false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReportingBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
    ...
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {
            materialUebersichtPDF = generateUebersichtMaterial();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you Q/A is a duplicate of several other StackOverflow Q/A? Please remove it then

Comment: It shows the complete way of generating a Jasper-Report include subreport that will be print as pdf in primefaces media. I think and hope the workflow could be usefull for others.

Comment: Yes I know, but improving the answer (duplicate) so it is easier and more generically found is better. No (largely) duplication, if things change in a Framework, only one answer needs to be improved... etc... Developers in many cases search for to specific problems, so having a good generic answer is better imo (the fact that jasper reports is used does not play any role in the actual problem does it?)

Comment: Yes, you are totaly right. There is also a little subjectivity in the answer because I was trying about one day until I found the solution ;-).
btw... how can I flag the question as duplicate?